# GMS or ThreadPoolExecutor error while HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am new to developing android apps! 
In this piece of code I tried to connect my app to an API server and just the connection matters!
I wanted to show the JSON file with a Toast message when clicked on button
This is my code for `HttpUrlConnection` but when I click on button the result `toast` is shown empty
Also the error log is provided below

```
register_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                new JSONTask().execute(main_url);


            }
        });





public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection=null;
            BufferedReader reader=null;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                connection.connect();


                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));


                String line = "";
                while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null){
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }

                return stringBuilder.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                if (connection != null){
                    connection.disconnect();
                }

                if (reader != null){
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

And this is the error log

```
2019-12-28 10:31:23.264 2718-3484/? E/aofp: Phenotype API error. Event # bybz@2cda59b4, EventCode: 12 [CONTEXT service_id=51 ]
    aoeg: 29503
        at aofv.b(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):23)
        at aofp.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):92)
        at aofp.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):79)
        at aale.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):19)
        at bkdz.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):2)
        at squ.b(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):37)
        at squ.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at swz.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2019-12-28 10:31:23.268 2718-3484/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=51, operation=GetCommittedConfigurationOperationCall
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 29503, resolution=null}]
        at aofp.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):100)
        at aofp.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):79)
        at aale.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):19)
        at bkdz.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):2)
        at squ.b(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):37)
        at squ.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at swz.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2019-12-28 10:31:23.268 2718-4351/? E/NetRec: [190] alcj.a: Could not retrieve server token for package com.google.android.apps.gcs
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: rjk: 29503: 
        at avgu.b(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):3)
        at avgu.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):20)
        at alcj.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):1)
        at alcj.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):4)
        at alce.getHeaders(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):2)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):9)
        at sjg.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):1)
        at byj.executeRequest(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):1)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):5)
        at sjj.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):13)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):7)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):2)
     Caused by: rjk: 29503: 
        at rpj.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):4)
        at aodi.b(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):2)
        at aofv.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):6)
        at aale.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):30)
        at bkdz.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):2)
        at squ.b(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):37)
        at squ.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at swz.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```